# array.splice is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to remove an item from an array of unchecked with this bit of code.

```
function filterSearch() {
var cats = [];

$('.filter-by-type input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  var cat = $(this).attr('name') + ', ';
   if(this.checked) {
      cats += cat;
   } else {
      cats.splice(cats.indexOf(cat), 1);
   }

  console.log(cats);
 });

}

filterSearch();
```

I am getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: cats.splice is not a function`

Basically I want to add the value to the `cats[]` array if the item is checked and removed if unchecked. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`cats` is a array. Here:

```
if(this.checked) {
   cats += cat;
        ^^
} else {
   cats.splice(cats.indexOf(cat), 1);
}
```

You are trying to concatenate an array with the `+=` operator, `cats` is now a string, you should use the [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push) method instead.

```
if(this.checked) {
   cats.push(cat);
} else {
   cats.splice(cats.indexOf(cat), 1);
}
```

Comment: More specifically, `cats += cat` replaces the `cats` array with a *string*, as can be seen by testing it in the JavaScript console.